# Heatmap creation

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I am trying to create heatmaps showing potential savings/costs within a certain area.

[image: the screenshot below will show the columns I have for each individual vector point]

however when I go on to the heatmap creation, My advanced parameters do not let me select further options for the radius and weight
[image: as seen here]

I believe this may be down to the amount of data I have, or the pixels/columns.

Can someone see the error or the correct way to create this heatmap?

Comment: The tool probably expect numeric field for the radius and weight parameter make sure that's the case, if not use the field calculator to convert your data to new numeric field